# How to 'pickle' an object to a certain directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Normally, executing the following code will **[pickle](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)** an object to a file in my `current` directory:

```
fp = open('somefile.txt', 'wb')
pickle.dump(object, fp)
```

How do I re-direct the output from `pickle.dump` to a different directory?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
with open('/full/path/to/file', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(object, f)
```

Comment: Cool thanks. Is your way to open the file preferred to what I did? Or more "pythonic", I should say.

Comment: It is preferred, because it closes the file for you in a `try: ... finally: f.close()` fashion. You should read about the Python context manager, it's a really great feature in many situations.

Answer (score 7):

How about combination of pathlib and with, I think it more flexible and safer.

```py
# from python 3.4
from pathlib import Path
my_path = Path("{path to you want to set root like . or ~}") / "path" / "to" / "file"
with my_path.open('wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(object, fp)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just try

```
import pickle
filepath = r'<FolderName>/<FileName>.pkl'
pickle.dump(<model>, open(filepath, 'wb'))
```

so final code look likes
If your Folder name is Models
and you wanted to pickle randomForest Model

```
import pickle
filepath = r'Models/rfPickle.pkl'
pickle.dump(randomForest, open(filepath, 'wb'))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to save the file to a sub-folder located inside the folder containing your code you can use the pathlib module. This will allow the code to work even if its location is moved on your computer, or you code is added to a different machine.

import the module:

```
from pathlib import Path
```

Set root equal to your current folder:

```
root = Path(".")
```

Create a path to your sub-folder and file name:

```
my_path = root / "my_sub_folder" / "my_file_name"
```

Open your file, dump data to your file, close your file:

```
my_file = open(my_path, 'wb')
my_file = pickle.dump("data_to_save", my_file)
my_file.close()
```

- Note if your my_file doesn't currently exist you will want to create it before running this code. *